# mail not send througth action mailer rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying implementing send mail through action mailer in rails 
related code are..

development.rb

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 9292}

 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address     =>"smtp.gmail.com",
    :domain      =>"gmail.com",
   :port        => 587,
   :user_name   =>"Debasis",
   :password    =>"************",
   :authentication =>"plain",
   :enable_starttls_auto =>true
   }
```

my mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "bkdebasish90@gamil.com"
    def registration_confirmation(user)
    mail(:to=>user.email, :subject =>"Registered")
   end
end
```

users.controller is

```
  def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   respond_to do |format| 
if @user.save
  UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver_now
  format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.'       
}
  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
     else
  format.html { render :new }
  format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
     end
    end
```

but my email is not sent...what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ca see you are using Gmail, so assuming you are using 2-factor authentication, you need to create an app specific password to put into config, rather than your own.

Try setting `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` in your development environment file to see any errors that happen

Comment: can you explain about 2-factor authentication,

Comment: I would suggest to check the log using 'raise_delivery_errors' because I am just making an assumption. Especially if you don't know what it is, its probably not activated. You can read more here [Google 2-Step Verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/#tab=how-it-works), but in a nutshell you tie your phone to the account, so that you can confirm your sign-ins with it. Moreover you need to generate unique password for every application that is using your Google Account

Comment: i have tried...using raise_delivery_errors...its display this error..Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in UsersController#create             535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at but i already check my password

Comment: I think your username should be the email, so Debasis@gmail.com                  Otherwise it might be 2-factor indeed, you should check your google account

Comment: after removing tls auto=true its remove the username and password error but one new error cretae from controller..isSocketError in UsersController#create
getaddrinfo: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

Comment: Why did you remove it? it just detects if STARTTLS is enabled in your SMTP server. Did you check what I asked you to? Use email as username or check if you have 2-factor authentication?